# There is a way to select which virtual fields I want to load with my data? Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have some virtual fields on my entity and there's a point on my controller that I dont want to load them, just don't need these values. Is there a way to NOT load the virtual fields whithin my

```
$this->Model->get($id)
```

?

Something like `unset` or `['_virtual' => false]`

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Virtual fields are just that, they are virtual. They don't get "loaded" from the database. If you don't access them, they never really exist. Please clarify what specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry, actully I was confused about the virtual field and its exposed version, I thought that I need have it on my $_virtual array and his get method, but its not it. I realized that  the $_virtual array was to show this data within called objects and arrays, to actully use the value that is expected just need to call the property name based on the get convention and not necessarly have it on the $_virtual property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the virtual fields are actually generated *until* something explicitly executes their getter, ie. a `toArray()` call, which could be automatically triggered just by displaying the Entity by sticking it in `debug()` or `_serializing` it for a JSON response. Simply calling `Model->get()` does not seed these virtual values.

So I believe there's few options:

**Option 1:** If you *normally* want those virtual fields in most places but just not this one time in this one get() call, either:

**(a)** change the [virtual listing at runtime](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html#exposing-virtual-fields) after the get(), ex:

```
$entity = $this->Model->get($id)
$entity->setVirtual([]); // Or list just the properties you still want in the array
```

.**. or (b)** mark them as [hidden at runtime](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html#hiding-fields) so they aren't referenced automatically in any displayed values, ex:

```
$entity = $this->Model->get($id)
$entity->setHidden(['virtual_field_you_want_to_hide']);
```

**Option #2:** If actually you *don't* want this field to be output most of the time anyways (in JSON exports and whatnot) and only want to reference it on demand, then that's what Cake's [$_hidden](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html#hiding-fields) is for, in the entity mark it $_hidden:

```
class MyEntity extends Entity
{
    protected $_virtual = ['my_field'];
    protected $_hidden = ['my_field'];

    public function _getMyField(){
        return 'my_field_value'; 
    }
}
```

With this, simply calling get() won't call the virtual field's getter, and neither will displaying the entity in any way. Only calling the field directly will call the `_getMyField` getter, ex:

```
$entity = $this->Model->get($id);
print_r($entity); // Doesn't output my_field by default
echo $entity->my_field; // Only now call _getMyField, and this outputs "my_field_value"
```

Comment: OH thats it, it took me so much time to figure it out by myself ahhaha, if I've had asked this sooner your answer would have helped me avoid a lot of mind overclock hahahah. Thank you!

I've tested the setHidden option and it keep showing the results of the $_virtual properties (which is set on the hidden array) on the result, is it right? I'm trying to enhance my system performance, thats why I dont need my virtual fields to select data from the database at this moment.

Btw if the $_virtual is empty calling these values with the setVirtual method works perfectly;

Comment: Where you still seeing virtual properties, is it from debug()? I only now just remembered that EntityTrait has a special __debugInfo function that manually calls each virtual field regardless of hidden when you output an entity with debug(), so I was bit off on that. But it shouldn't show in like JSON outputs or something that just is calling toArray under the hood

Comment: Again, to be clear, having virtual fields adds *nothing* to your database overhead. They act entirely in PHP code on data that's already in memory, and only when explicitly requested by something (though that something could be a JSON conversion or debug output).

Comment: That's a good point and certainly true in my examples & probably most people's usage for virtual fields - but there's nothing stopping you from having virtual fields that *do* make database calls or do some complex calculations, however - I'm sorta assuming that's the case here